# Is there a way I can create a Heroku backup from a appliation method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to create a button in my application to make a database capture in Heroku. So I can backup everything with just one click.

I am searching on the internet, but untill now I didn't find anything. Is there some sort of Heroku API to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`heroku-api-postgres`**](https://github.com/coorasse/heroku-api-postgres)

```
postgres_api_client = Heroku::Api::Postgres.connect_oauth(ENV['HEROKU_OAUTH_TOKEN'])
backups_client = postgres_api_client.backups
backup = backups_client.capture(app_id, database_id)
```

Details on how to get `database_id`

https://github.com/coorasse/heroku-api-postgres#how-do-i-get-the-database_id-

I haven't tested the capture API. Although I am using the backups api and it works great.

---

**Official Platform API gem** - https://github.com/heroku/platform-api
 but it doesn't support backups

Comment: This will help. Thanks!